# c program to demonstrate use of Exit Handler

Tags: c

I am studying c language and in that there is exit handler. I am not getting exactly what it is. So to understand it programatically I need a c program demonstrate use of Exit Handler.

Comment: Have a look at the `atexit()` function: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write one yourself and experiment with it.  Your starting point will be something like:

```
void myExitFunction(void) 
{
    ...
}

int main() 
{                        
   atexit(myExitFunction);
}
```